# Passing object from one activity from another activity

Tags: android

I like to pass object from one activity from another activity. I implemented Serializable.
But somehow, the object is not passed  and at the receiver side I get NULL.
Can pls check where is wrong?

```
public class TrackerInfo implements Serializable{
  /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   String Idnumber;
  String Simcardnumber;
  String Description;
  String Model;
  String time;

  public String getSimcardnumber() {
      return Simcardnumber;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
      return Description;
  }

  public String getModel() {
      return Model;
  }
  public void setModel(String model) {
      this.Model = model;
  }

  public String getTime() {
      return time;
  }

  public void setInforFromCursor(Cursor cursor){
      this.Idnumber = cursor.getString(1);
      this.Simcardnumber = cursor.getString(2);
      this.Description = cursor.getString(3);
      this.Model = cursor.getString(4);
      this.time = cursor.getString(5);
  }}
```

At sender side,

```
@Override
    public void itemSelected(String id) {
        //get Tracker info
        dbHelper = new TrackerDBAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchListByIDNum(id);
        TrackerInfo tracker = new TrackerInfo();
        tracker.setInforFromCursor(cursor);
        dbHelper.close();
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> obj = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        obj.put("TRAKCER", tracker);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("bundleobj", obj);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailMapView.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("bundleobj", b);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

At receiver side,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_map_view);
    try {  setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_map_view);
         Bundle bn = new Bundle();
         bn = getIntent().getExtras();
         HashMap<String, Object> getobj = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         getobj = (HashMap<String, Object>) bn.getSerializable("bundleobj");
         trackerinfo = (TrackerInfo) getobj.get("TRACKER");
    } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("Err", e.getMessage());
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes, please read Sajmon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707297/1267661), but you are also putting a Bundle in a Bundle, but only reading from the outer Bundle.  Remove code like this:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("bundleobj", obj);
```

And put the data directly into the Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailMapView.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("bundleobj", obj);

// You may need to help the compiler by casting it to a Serializable
//intent.putExtra("bundleobj", (Serializable) obj);
```

---

In order to use your double Bundle method you need to fetch both "bundleobj" tags:

```
 bn = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("bundleobj");
 HashMap<String, Object> getobj = (HashMap<String, Object>) bn.getSerializable("bundleobj");
```

Comment: you right man, i updated my answer, check it out and for you for sure +1 btw, why i can't refer your nick in comment? O_o

Comment: Comments notifications (`@Sam`) are weird on SO... It didn't suggest my name because I already get a notification since this is my answer. Good catch with `"TRAKCER"` and `"TRACKER"`, I didn't see that at first. (Already +1)

Comment: oh, yes for sure :) now i understand. :)

Comment: Thanks Men, that is why stackoverflow where we can rely on with people like you

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is here:

```
obj.put("TRAKCER", tracker);
```

You are adding tracker to `HashMap` with key **`TRAKCER`**

But here:

```
getobj.get("TRACKER");
```

You are trying to get object with key **`TRACKER`** but keys are not equal and this is reason of **`NPE`**. You need to fix

```
obj.put("TRACKER", tracker);
```

Now keys are equal so it should works.

### Update:

As @Sam pointed out you wrapped your `HashMap` into Bundle and Bundle into Intent. So if your approach had work you need to do following:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> obj = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
obj.put("TRACKER", tracker);

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("trackerObj", obj);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailMapView.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("bundleObj", b);
```

And for retrieving `HashMap`:

```
Bundle wrapper = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundleObj"); // this Bundle contains HashMap
HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) wrapper.getSerializable("trackerObj");
```

### Recommendation:

How @Sam pointed out again, better and cleaner way is to wrap directly your `HashMap` as Serializable into Intent with `putExtra("trackerObj", obj)` method and then easily retrieve it as

```
HashMap<String, Object> o = (HashMap<String, Object>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("trackerObj");
```

Comment: Sajmon is right.
That's the reason a (static final) string could help avoiding typos :)